# Apple Pie in a Jar Drink

Tags: pie, drinks, alcohol, apples

I was recently out of town for a business trip and heard some people talking about some type of drink that they had at a party called Apple Pie in a Jar.  I was curious if anyone else has heard of this and would know how to make it?  It sounds interesting especially since I like Apple Pie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're talking about [this recipe](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/apple-pie-in-a-jar-drink/).

Looks like some apple juice, cider, cinnamon,sugar, and some grain alcohol.

Comment: I have also heard of a similar drink consisting of mulled cider, Tuaca liqueur, and whipped cream.